# How long can I keep beef warm in a roaster oven?

Tags: meat, storage

Can I keep about 10 lbs of already grilled hamburgers warm in a roaster oven overnight.  They will be submerged in beef broth......

Answer (score 2):

It will be safe if the temperature is consistently above 140 F / 63 C, but it is almost certainly a very poor idea from a quality perspective.

**If the temperature does *not* stay above 140 F, then you are incubating the hamburgers, inviting pathogens to grow:  that is dangerous and a very bad idea.**

Hamburgers are one of those items that are best served immediately upon being cooked; there is no really good way to hold them or reheat them and have the same experience.

If you have to have them cooked in advance, I would refrigerate them and then reheat with the method of your choice, such as in a moderate oven (for a large quantity).

Comment: Even I, known for my lax food hygiene, have to agree with the cat: that sounds less than safe. I would do exactly what it proposes.